# Ruby on Rails api json response methods and include

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have technical question i have user model which have many questions so in my API controller i do:

```
render json: user, :include => {
        :questions => {
            :only => [:text]
        },
    }
```

Now i want to add to JSON response question count. How can i do that in best way. I know that i can create method inside model : count_question and after that do:

```
render json: user, :include => {
        :questions => {
            :only => [:text]
        },
    }, :methods => [
        :count_question
    ]
```

and my response will be good. But is there better way to put that information to JSON. I want to avoid add method inside model. Is it possible to determine this count inside json renderer?

Greetings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout [JSON API and Active Model Serializers with Rails](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lQOLrycmXC4)

This will hep you out format your JSON.

Comment: Thank You for advise. This is exacly what I was looking for. Upvoted